# Is silent model destroy possible

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to do a silent destroy on a model? I've tried

```
model.destroy({ silent: true });
```

This will not remove the model from the collection. If this shouldn't be possible, how can the same effect be attained?

Comment: What's your goal? You don't want to have the model in the collection and you don't want to fire an event or you just want it removed from the server ( send "DELETE" ) and not changing the collection?

Comment: I don't want it to fire an event or be removed from server (it doesn't exist on server and never will)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.remove` to remove the model from the collection

```
collection.remove(model, { silent: true });
```

This will remove the model from the collection, but will never destroy it on the server ( will not send `DELETE` request.